# C# ODBC Simple Select With Criteria Doesn't find a Match

Tags: c#

I am pretty sure I am doing everything right here, and there is some type of tricky bug behind this issue, hopefully someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

All I am trying to do is select a count of rows that meet my criteria.

A single column from my Access database is like this -

```
Product Reference
AHD12
OSI133
SO-ERT1
.. 
.. 
..
```

Here is a small snippet of my code -

```
using (conn)
{
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product, conn)
    int recordCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**recordCount = 4572**

Then I try the following -

```
using (conn)
{
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product where 'Product Reference' ='AHD12' ", conn);
    int recordCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**recordCount = 0**

As you can see, the Product Reference AHD12 does exist in the database, but it just doesn't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try [Product Reference] instead of 'Product Reference'

Comment: Already tried this, still gives a 0

Comment: Does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE Trim([Product Reference]) = 'AHD12'` work?

Comment: I think it is actually the single quotes around 'AHD12'.  In Access it would be double quotes.  Still need [Product Reference] in brackets.  Try this:  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE [Product Reference] = \"AHD12\""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Double quotes may help you (Tested in SQL server)

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product where \"Product Reference\" ='AHD12'";
```

or try using backtick

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product where `Product Reference` ='AHD12';
```

Comment: The  \"Product Reference\" Solution worked perfectly, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax for Access with field names with spaces is:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product where [Product Reference] ='AHD12'";
```